# Remove documents based on array field $size and comparison operators

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Conversation` mongoose model with a `members` field:

```
const Conversation = new Schema({
    ...
    members: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
    ...
});
```

I would like to remove conversations with 1 or less members.
Currently I do it like this:

```
Conversation.remove({    
    $or: [
        { members: { $size: 1 } },
        { members: { $size: 0 } }
    ]
});
```

I wondered if mongoose/mongodb support something like the following (**not working**):

```
Conversation.remove({    
    members: {
        $size: { $lte: 1 }
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) of `$size`.

> $size does not accept ranges of values. To select documents based on
>   fields with different numbers of elements, create a counter field that
>   you increment when you add elements to a field.
>
> Queries cannot use indexes for the $size portion of a query, although
>   the other portions of a query can use indexes if applicable.

---

**Adapt your shema**

```
const Conversation = new Schema({
    ...
    members: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
    nbMembers: {
     type: Number,
     select: false,
    },
    ...
});
```

**Remove case**

```
  Conversation.remove({ 
    nbMembers: {
       $lte: 1, 
    },
  });
```

---

When you add an `_id` in `members`, don't forget to add `+1` on `nbMembers` [($inc)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)